# PowerShell Regex for repeating character

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a CSV-File that sometimes contains empty lines that I want to filter out of the result. When I know my input, I know how many `commas` to expect and filter them out like this:

```
"Test 1, Text A,", "Test 2, Text B,", ",," | Where {$_ -ne ",," }
```

How would the regex be to also filter out empty lines regardless of how many `commas` there are? Because I never know upfront how many columns there will be.

In the following example I would like to be able to retrieve the same result as in the previous example:

```
"Test 1, Text A,", "Test 2, Text B,", ",,", ",", ",,," | Where {$_ -ne ",," }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
"Test 1, Text A,", "Test 2, Text B,", ",,", ",", ",,," 
         | Where {!([regex]"^[,]+$").match($_).Success}
```

Which search for lines which has more than one comma between begin 
(char `^`) and end of the string (char `$`)

You can also simplify this expression to below one:

```
"Test 1, Text A,", "Test 2, Text B,", ",,", ",", ",,," | Where {$_ -notmatch "^[,]+$"}
```

Comment: Thank you Garath, that last one was exactly what I was looking for :)